# outlook configuration (not allowed word ) in windows 10 virtual machine

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, vmware, vmware-workstation, imap

I am trying to solve a problem my gmail account is almost full in its capacity to 14 GB (15 Gb is maximum limit) so I want to download all emails with attachments on my desktop and save attachments in computer.
I have enabled pop3 and imap on my gmail account.
Now today when I tried to configure outlook 2016 which comes with Windows 10 I get following error
[image: imap could not be configured]

ok based on some comments I come to conclusion DNS name resolution is probably not happening properly.
[image: dns name prob1]
[image: dns name prob2]
[image: dns name prob3]

I am doing all this in VMware workstation 15 virtual machine running Windows 10.
So here are a few screenshots of VMware network settings as well.
[image: screen1]
[image: screen2]
[image: virtual network editor1]
[image: virtual network editor2]
IP address of virtual machine is

```
Windows IP Configuration Virtual Machine


Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::avve:fe6f:c3a4:ae3e%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.129
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.2
```

I did not set it. Windows virtual machine got it automatically. Is there any mistake in this?

ip configuration o of host machine

Windows IP Configuration Host OS

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : input2::38df:deaf:8a0b:fab6%21
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.40.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : input2::input2:defe:98c4:c5dc%15
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi 2: (Dlink USB Wifi)

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi: (Realtek On Board Wifi)

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : domain.name
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : input2::input2:input2:5416:72a4%13
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.13
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : input2::1262:input2:input2:d1d5%13
                                       192.168.1.1
```

smtp and imap port settings based on gmail help link in comment
[image: smtp and imap settings]

Right now this seems to be a VMware configuration problem so till I solve that on this thread [connecting virtual machines in workstation to desired vmnet out of 3 vmnets](https://superuser.com/questions/1507721/connecting-virtual-machines-in-workstation-to-desired-vmnet-out-of-3-vmnets) I am putting this for hold currently as I have tried setting SSL/TLS as mentioned in answer below some how my virtual machines have lost internet connectivity.

Comment: Make certain you have your ISP's settings for address, ports and security.  Then set the account up manually. Control Panel, Mail, and use the buttons for email account. Set up manually and you should be good to go.

Comment: I have no idea to do so I am trying to use VMware virtual machine for running Windows 10 and there I am configuring outlook 2010.

Comment: Go Gmail help.  Settings are here:  https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7126229?hl=en

Comment: Please remove all the networking screenshots, as they're only serving to clutter the question, providing no relevant info, since your issue lies in the misconfiguration of the gmail account properties in Outlook... see @Perry's answer below, changing the Incoming encryption type to SSL/TLS and the Outgoing encryption type to either STARTTLS or SSL/TLS on port 587 _(incoming: 993 SSL/TLS; outgoing 587 STARTTLS || SSL/TLS)_.

Comment: Right now this seems to be a VMware related problem because I have tried that SSL/TLS in my outlook settings once I restore internet in my VMware I will come back to this question till then let all the things be as it is.

Comment: the problem of virtual machine not having internet connectivity has been solved it can be read here https://superuser.com/questions/1507968/virtual-machine-not-having-internet-connectivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the screenshot, you didn’t set the encrypt method, is that?

Refer to my Gmail account settings:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Make sure “Allow Less Secure Apps” is turned on for your gmail account.

Also find [this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/991a1f63-cf7b-4255-a95c-c9ccb9e3ce3b/outlookunble-to-add-account?forum=outlook) which may be helpful.

Comment: _"“Allow Less Secure Apps"_ **should not** be turned on for the Outlook desktop application, as Outlook supports Google's SSO.  Outgoing port should be `587` to enable usage of TLS, which is more efficient than SSL and Type of Encryption should either be STARTTLS or SSL/TLS.

Comment: see this screenshot https://drive.google.com/open?id=18Ae5YiLSZEztbMmCrf2qj5jLFUpVPQWt   gmail blocked sign in from outlook 2016 considering it to be a less secure app  https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Y2ckKGXigHaduaT-2uv88Wln0sFqALgY  I changed the port settings as in your screenshot https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sLbbpJbOwZJSohlX6AZAiTfwzngAfuLk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: here is a screenshot account settings fail still for some reason https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tbxf-2lIgtu2vIV7yldrfKk2JKO2dlmX/view?usp=sharing less secure apps are also allowed

Comment: ok I think I got it why gmail is not allowing outlook to work is mentioned here "since July 15, 2014, Google has strengthened the protection of accounts by blocking applications that use simple validation for access the Gmail mailbox (such as Outlook). Currently, Outlook does not support OAuth and 2-Step Verification, so the only way to allow a connection for Gmail via Outlook is to use the App-Specific Password." https://theitbros.com/outlook-cannot-connect-to-gmail/  I was able to launch a Ubuntu 19.10 virtual machine instance and configured thunderbird it worked in it.