# connecting virtual machines in workstation to desired vmnet out of 3 vmnets

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, virtual-machine, vmware

I am having three vmnets in VMware workstation.
vmnet0 vmnet1 vmnet8
VMnet0 is bridged/automatic  I tried playing with it changing lan card assigned to it.
[image: vmnet0 having multiple lan cards to connect]

Now following is configuration of vmnet0 at the time of writing this question
[image: vmnet0]

and vmnet8 is
[image: vmnet8 NAT sharing host IP with VMs]

The virtual machine IP address is
Windows IP Configuration in Virtual Machine

```
Ethernet adapter Ethernet0:
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : localdomain
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : ffff::ffff:fe6f:c3a4:ae3e%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.129
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.152.2
```

This is in range 192.168.152.X this is in vmnet8 so this virtual machine is connected to vmnet8
The setting here which I understand is that virtual machine is connected to vmnet8 which has only one Wifi card that is onboard Realtek
adapter which it is showing me as 2 adapters as in screenshot

> Realtek RTL8723DE 802.11b/g/n PCI e Adapter
>   Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller #2

vmnet8_b
[image: only 2 adaptors in VMware]

which I think is same LAN card (and is not connected to internet)

Now if I want Virtual machine to be connected to VMnet0 to the  bridged LAN Card DLink DWA-131  Wireless Network mode so
that I can bridge the Wifi connection to access point via USB Wifi Card. DLink  or even If I wish to connect VM to Vmnet0
in NAT it is giving me errors.
[image: vmnet0 nat error]

I am not able to understand how to connect virtual machines to desired VMnets.
i.e. If I want to connect vm to Vmnet0 or vmnet1 or vmnet8 how can I choose desired vmnet.What  mistake I am doing here.
please guide me to some tutorial which can help me or some link that might have explained this concept better.
I am not able to understand how to do bridging for virtual machines to desired vmnet as a result my VMs are not having internet
connectivity.
I have my internet connectivity in host machine on Wifi2 connection which is my DLink USB Wifi. So I want Virtual machines to be 
connected to a vmnet0 which is connected to DLink in bridged mode as in vmnet8 I am not having an option to share DLink USB Wifi in bridged mode.

The question is simple how to connect virtual machines to internet using USB Wifi Adaptor which can be seen [here](https://www.amazon.in/D-Link-DWA-171-Wireless-Dual-Band-Adapter/dp/B00CL58JYQ) in my case in screenshots.

I am not able to get Virtual machines use Vmnet0 because Vmnet0 is where I can see my USB Wifi Card but Dlink is not visible in vmnet1 or vmnet8 as adaptor even though I want to use bridge/NAT on them it should be available there in drop down menu to do NAT or bridge it is not.showing there

VMnet0 can see the mentioned card. What I was trying that vmnet8 should  see the card and I do a NAT of virtual machines on vmnet8 and then bridge external USB lan card with vmnet8 using vmnet8 and no involvement of vmnet0 . What my understanding is different different vmnet in virtual machine can segment different virtual.machines in different lan segments then how can I give internet connectivity to my.virtual machines using those vmnet's is the involvement of vmnet0 a necessary condition.Cant this be achieved with a custom vmnet8 only. My understanding is vmnet8 is behaving like a virtual nic which can be connected bridged to external USB wifi device is this understanding wrong?

Comment: Your USB Internet is local to the host machine. Bridged Networking applies when your host is connected to an external DHCP server (Router). So make sure the Host machine has good internet and then use NAT Networking on the guest machine.  That will work. If you need to, close VMware, run the Network Editor separately, select the Admin button and reset the NAT network. Then close out, restart the host computer and then start the machine and check again

Comment: USB adaptor Dlink is basically a wifi lan card which is connected to a DHCP router which is giving me internet.

Comment: You confused me a bit with "USB Internet".  If it is a plain old Wireless adapter, then NAT or Bridged will work. I can and do use both. I am in a Linux machine with NAT networking and a DHCP server. I could equally well use Bridged

Comment: see this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/clPru.jpg vmnet8 is where all my virtual machines are connected and it is not showing me DLink Wifi 2 adaptor which is my USB adaptor in which I want to do same thing which you have done. DLink wifi adaptor I can see on vmnet0 but virtual machines are not connected to vmnet0. So that is what I want to know how to connect Virtual machines to vmnet0 or vmnet1 or vmnet8 depending upon usage. I have 2 Wifi adaptors I want second wifi adaptor which is my USB Wifi  dedicated for VMware works and connect that to internet as well.

Comment: Reset your VMware Network. Change vmnet8 to NAT and then reset it all

Comment: Here in this screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNUyb.jpg  I have done what you are saying or did I miss something?

Comment: That looks good (looks broadly like mine) and your guest should work with either NAT or Bridged (first network option)

Comment: So that is the question it is not working now re read the question.

Comment: So long as connected as shown the guest machine will connect to the outside or to the host for file sharing and so on. What other connection issue are you thinking about? Your question is very long so you may wish to edit it to a more concise problem statement

Comment: The question is long because I have given screenshots. Otherwise it is simple how to connect virtual machines to internet using USB Wifi Card which is Dlink in my case in screenshots. I am not able to get Virtual machines use Vmnet0 because Vmnet0 is where I can see my USB Wifi Card but Dlink is not visible in vmnet1 or vmnet8 as adaptor even though I want to use bridge/NAT on them it should be available there in drop down menu to do NAT or bridge it is not.showing there.

Comment: once all this works this is what I want to achieve https://itpro.outsidesys.com/2015/02/19/home-lab-with-pfsense-workstation/ I want to simulate an environment such that I have different lan segments for different virtual machines and then do some experiments like routing re-routing from different different interfaces.

Comment: I do not think this is a problem in your setup. If VMnet0 (Bridged) will not work with the card, the the card is not compatible. VMnet 8 (NAT) does not see a physical card as it connects inside the machine.

Comment: your second line gives me some clue "vmnet8 does not see physical card" how ever I want to be more confirmed so if you can give any link which can confirm this statement then that will help a bit. But then the question is how do I connect the Virtual machines to vmnet0? vmnet0 can see the external USB Wifi adaptor.

Comment: As I noted for VMnet0 it may be a compatibility issue. I have been using VMware Workstation since Version 1 nearly 2 decades ago, and Bridged networking has never failed. So I think it must be your card. Try a different wireless adapter.

Comment: VMnet0 can see the mentioned card. What I was trying that vmnet8 should  see the card and I do a NAT of virtual machines on vmnet8 and then bridge external USB lan card with vmnet8 using vmnet8 and no involvement of vmnet0 . What my understanding is different different vmnet in virtual machine can segment different virtual.machines in different lan segments then how can I give internet connectivity to my.virtual machines using those vmnet's is the involvement of vmnet0 a necessary condition.Cant this be achieved with a custom vmnet8 only. My understanding is vmnet8 is behaving like a virtual n

Comment: That was a bit confusing because you said you were tying to use VMnet0. VMnet8 is NAT and that just uses the VMware internal network card. You do not see it. You definitely can use Bridged networking on one machine and NAT on another. I do this. You can put two machines to two different IP addreses, and you can add another NAT adapter (Network Editor) to give another machine a different subnet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101879/discussion-between-political-science-and-john).